# Chicago Manual of Style / University of Chicago Press (la)tex formatting

Tags: chicago-style

I'm interested in writing a document following not only the Chicago Manual of Style in principle but also very literally the style used by the University of Chicago Press in their publishing. In other words, I'm not just trying to follow the style guidelines outlined in the manual, but also directly emulating the full style used in their publications.

Here is a sample page:

[image: Page from Chicago Manual of Style]

Obviously their style has a large number of rules (many more than used on that particular page) and I may not need to use all of them, but even a small subset would be painful to implement manually. So what I'm wondering is, is there an existing (la)tex template that has already implemented most or all of their style? When I search, I only find results for templates for their bibliography style, and that's more about following their guidelines rather than directly reproducing their formatting.

Comment: Look here: https://www.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/chicago You can find different types of manuals.

Comment: I know of no class file/setup that does all of the setups of the CMS. The question is a bit broad. Probably the best one can do is to start with the memoir class and then go step wise. Read the good memoir manual, and adapt piece by piece. And then if something in particular seems difficult, ask about just that part.

Comment: A quick search did not reveal which software is used by the CMoS publishers. You might ask them. Doubt if it is TeX. On one of the MS forums, a recent post (2022) implied that even MS Word does not have a template for CMoS. You can find software that applies CMoS rules to what you write, but does not format you pages like the CMoS itself. Bottom line: You may have to do it yourself, not necessarily with TeX.